# Linux find and replace Japanese string on filename

Tags: linux, replace, find

I need to find and replace a string in Japanese filenames in all subfolders.

I have tried all common find and replace commands but they do not seem to work with japanese characters.

Note: I do not want to remove all japanese characters only find and replace a certain string within the filename.

Comment: any filename example?

Comment: for example:　東京_名.php and I would like to replace the last character 名

Answer (score 0):

these are unicode characters, so you could find them with for example

`find | grep -P '[\x3041-\x3096]'`  (Hiragana)

`find | grep -P '[\x30A0-\x30FF]'`  (Katakana)

But you'd need to figure out the exact characters (unicode notation) you want to replace first.

However, it could be that your encoding is different. If you need to change encodings then use `convmv` , for example

```
convmv -f EUC-JP -t UTF-8 *
```

**update.** This script works for your example. I just copy/pasted the character.

```
SEARCH="名."  
REPLACE="_."

for x in *$CHAR*; do
 rename  "s/$SEARCH/$REPLACE/" $x
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that we are almost there, when I use find | grep -P '[\x3041-\x3096]' "I get range out of order in character class message", when I change the unicode for the characters I want to search, it just prints all the files on the folder but does not replace anything.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many commands this worked:

find . -type f | xargs rename 's/textofind/newtext/g'

I did not have to type the unicode notation, I could type directly the japanese characters on the command line.

For users that just want to find and erase the string, you can use the command like this:

find . -type f | xargs rename 's/textofind//g'